# how to update data from one table to another table with summ

Tags: sql, oracle

sorry if i confused you
iam working on billing software
my module is billing module using jsp i made all   struck on one pont i.e;
i have one item_receive table (info of items from ware house to outlet) and one stock table
i want to insert data from item_receive table to stock table.but in stock table if item already exists then it added and qty is summed without effecting the data of item_receive table
how and what i have to use

```
`create table item_receive(itemid number,item_name varchar2(10)......qty number,units number.....)

`create table stock(item_name varchar2(10),........totalqty number,.....)
```

Comment: you can consider using the MERGE statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to

1. insert a row into `stock` table if `item_name` does not already
   exist, and
2. update the row by adding the `qty` from `item_receive`
   table to `totalqty`,

then you can consider using the MERGE statement, as below:

```
MERGE INTO stock s
USING item_receive ir
ON s.item_name  = ir.item_name
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET s.totalqty = s.totalqty +  ir.qty
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (item_name, ..., totalqty, ...)
    VALUES (ir.item_name, ..., ir.qty, ...);
```